# How can I make Bootstrap thumbnail images the same height so that the thumbnail panels align?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm using Bootstrap thumbnails with SVG that I got from Wikipedia but for some reason the SVG are all different sizes so it causes the thumbnail panels to not align.

Using what method can I make the thumbnail images the same height so that the thumbnail panels align?

Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="Flag_of_England.svg" style="width: 100%;" alt="England Chat">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>England Chat</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="/chat" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Chat</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="Flag_of_Ireland.svg" style="width: 100%;" alt="Ireland Chat">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Ireland Chat</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="/chat" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Chat</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="Flag_of_Scotland.svg" style="width: 100%;" alt="Scotland Chat">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Scotland Chat</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="/chat" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Chat</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="Flag_of_Wales.svg" style="width: 100%;" alt="Wales Chat">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Wales Chat</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="/chat" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Chat</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are any Bootstrap built-in classes that would accomplish what you want.

Comment: You either resize your images so they all have the same aspect ratios or you set that ratio with CSS (which may stretch/squish the image in an undesirable way). You could possibly set as background image giving image elements a width/height ratio and use `background size: cover;` to fill the space (with some clipping).

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height, or like hungerstar said make the images the same dimensions.

Comment: They're SVG am I misunderstanding I thought SVG can be any size and same image?

Comment: @user6888062 what do you mean by _"same image?"_ SVGs are still based on a width and height even though they can be scaled up without a loss in clarity. You can override an SVG's root dimensions but it will stretch and squish just like a raster image (made of pixels). The issue you're facing is that the dimensional ratios of each image are different. The Ireland SVG might be 3:2 and Wales might be 4:3. If you maintain Ireland's ratio but try to match the height of Wales, it will overflow the container or get clipped (depending on parent properties).

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c1093cze/1/) of what you can do and what happens when source images do not share aspect ratios. When the images do not share the same aspect ratio you will have to stretch/squish them or clip them in order for them to have the same "height." Your options after that are to update all SVGs to have the same aspect ratio or have the image container have a consistent height, and not stretch images to fit, and accept that there will be more whitespace around some images so the content below them can share the same visual "baseline."

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like you'd need to adjust the height of images to align them, but it would have to be a fixed number which probably isn't ideal. You could made 2 rows, one for images and one for text, and as long as each row contained 4 rows with class="col-md-3" the content would all align vertically, but not sure there's another way around it

Comment: You're right the content below the images would share the same top line but the the gap between image base and top of content would be irregular.